# hide fullscreen button not working

Tags: javascript, button, gallery, show-hide

I am trying to hide FS button like my arrow keys on royal slider but it wont work and I dont know why...

royalslider.css line cca 50:

```
.rsArrow,
.rsNav,
.rsThumbsArrow,
.rsFullscreenBtn {
     opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition:opacity 0.3s linear;
    transition:opacity 0.3s linear;
}
```

and certifikat.html js:

```
<script>
    var slider = $('.royalSlider'),
        btn =  slider.find('.rsFullscreenBtn').addClass('rsHidden');
    slider.hover(function() {
        btn.removeClass('rsHidden');
    }, function() {
        btn.addClass('rsHidden');
    });
</script>
```

files: [download](http://leteckaposta.cz/223445023)

**Edit:**

I Found this working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.royalSlider').mouseover(function(){
    $('.rsFullscreenBtn').removeClass('rsHidden');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.rsFullscreenBtn').addClass('rsHidden');
});
});
```

But how to add class rsHidden for rsFullscreenBtn before that mouseover? This button should be hidden already, before mouseover... Thnaks

Comment: I believe `.hover()` is deprecated. You should use `mouseenter` and `mouseout`.

Comment: And how to keep the class before mouseover?